# Permission on launcher activity. App isn't installed error

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-launcher

I am working on an app which can also be launched from another app. Lets call them "Called app" and "Calling app". I am adding a permission to the launcher activity of "the called app" with protectionLevel "signature". However, when I add this permission, I am not able to launch the "called app" from the app icon. It says "App isn't installed". I also tried with the protectionLevel "dangerous". It gives the same error.

I suppose the issue could be because I have provided a custom permission to the launcher activity and system doesn't know about it. When I remove the permission, I am able to launch the app. My question is : Is it safe to leave the launcher activity without any permission ? Or Is there any other way to protect the launcher activity so that I can launch the "called app" normally from the app icon and also from the "calling app" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I suppose the issue could be because I have provided a custom permission to the launcher activity and system doesn't know about it.

Not the "system" — the home screen. There are thousands of home screen implementations for Android, both pre-installed ones and ones available from distribution channels like the Play Store. None of them have a `<uses-permission>` element for your custom permission, and so none of them can launch your activity that is defended by that permission.

> Is it safe to leave the launcher activity without any permission ?

How are we supposed to know? You, at best, are the only person who knows what this activity does. Your question is akin to asking "is it safe for my Web server to have a public home page?".

> Or Is there any other way to protect the launcher activity so that I can launch the "called app" normally from the app icon and also from the "calling app" ?

Either your activity can be started by:

- anything (including home screens), by having an `<intent-filter>` and no `android:permission` attribute, o
- only by some app that you wrote that holds your custom permission, by having an `<intent-filter>` with an `android:permission` attribute, or
- only by another activity in the same app, by not having an `<intent-filter>`

Those are your three choices. Nobody but you can tell you which of those three choices is appropriate for this activity.

However, you need to understand the threats and risks, then decide how to protect against those threats, rather than randomly typing in security-related stuff and assuming that you are doing something useful. In this case, if you specifically want the home screen to be able to start this activity, what is the specific risk that you see from other apps being able to start this activity?